# google search console - Video outside the viewport

Tags: html, google-search-console

I am getting outside the viewport for below code

`<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tXdLPCKVLB4" data-gtm-yt-inspected-6="true" id="648650304" data-gtm-yt-inspected-481802_1062="true" title="The Pros And Cons Of Paying For Social Placement" width="560" height="315"></iframe></p>`

Please help how to fix this